# How do I install an external library in Dev-c++? (raylib)

Tags: c++, c, libraries, dev-c++, raylib

I want to include an external library called "raylib" on Dev-C++. I downloaded the library with .zip extension from github and tried to install it with Dev-C++ package installer, but it gives me an erorr and doesn't work. I exctracted it and tried other things like adding the library folder in the "Library" section in "Compiler Option" but it was useless. Could you help me please?

Comment: Terminology: You don't "Install" a library. You "Link" it. Knowing the right term may make your searching easier next time.

Comment: @user4581301 Well, before you can link to a library, you might need to "install" it.

Comment: True enough, but at the "Get the IDE to recognize the library" stage of the problem, you have to hope this has already been done.

Comment: You probably need to compile the github project from source using whatever compiler you are using with Dev C++